# Passing a value to a function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parameter-passing

I hope you understand what I mean to ask, since I find it hard to formulate the question properly. I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm using it jQuery in my website to rotate a DIV so the underlying DIV shows up. It's working perfectly. Now the only thing I want is PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons. I want to do this as the following; If e.g. the container2 rotate position is unequal to 0, then skip that one and check the rotate position for the next div, so it knows which div is still at 0 and then can rotate so the underlying div shows up. (its sorta like a book). I know how if\else statements work, the only trouble I have is passing the degree to the if else statement. This is an example code of what my statements look like now. I tried creating a variable, but I made a complete mess and still I seem unable to make it work. I hope someone can help me. This is an example code of what I use now.

```
$(".homeclick").click(function(){
    $("#container2").rotate({animateTo:150})
    $("#container").rotate({animateTo:0})
```

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: Hi Saranya, thank you for your comment. Well it's not much of a problem I encountered in my code, I'm just completely stuck to begin with so I'm not sure a jsFiddle would help in this case. I tried to explain the question as good as possible, I can try it again tho. In the code I posted the containers get rotated to 150 (I think its degrees) Now I need a new piece of else\if code that checks if the div position is at 150 or at 0 degrees. I just don't know how to pass that value to the else\if statement. Hope this clears up my question a bit!

Comment: Can you share  some visual reference of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, sure. http://luukvanaggelen.com/test/test2.html This is the website. Try to click on Home and Info, and the Home button on the left. That is the functions I added to the website. The function I'm trying to add now at the PREVIOUS and NEXT buttons ('Vorige' and 'Volgende'). To make this work I want to implement an else\if statement that checks if the div is turned up, or still at 0. The only thing I don't know is how to pass that value to the else\if statement. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sjUQe/

```
$(".homeclick").click(function(){
    $("#container2").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(150deg)');
    $("#container2").css('transform', 'rotate(150deg)');
    $("#container").css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(0deg)');
    $("#container").css('transform', 'rotate(0deg)');    
});
```

<----------------------------------------------->
UPDATE:

then you might look for this:
just rename container id to container1 container2 ... etc and then

```
var max_container = 2;
var min_container = 0;
var container = 1;
    $(volgende).click(function(){if ( container < max_container ) $(('#container'+container)).rotate({animateTo:150});container++;})
    $(vorige).click(function(){if ( container > min_container ) $(('#container'+container)).rotate({animateTo:0});container--;})
```

Comment: I have a working plugin that works and does this, it's not a matter of how to rotate, the rotate is working. Its just a general jQuery question. In the code I posted the containers get rotated to 150 (I think its degrees). That is all working. However I need a new piece of else\if code that checks if the div position is at 150 or at 0 degrees. (The values in the example code) I just don't know how to pass that value to the else\if statement.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check some state on your dom tree to determine which node is currently "active".

One common way is to add a class to the node :

```
function rotate($oldActive, $newActive){
    $oldActive.removeClass('active').rotate({animateTo: 150});
    $newActive.addClass('active').rotate({animateTo: 0});
}

$('#next').click(function(){
    var $old = $('.active');
    var $new = $old.next();
    rotate( $old, $new );
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    var $old = $('.active');
    var $new = $old.prev();
    rotate( $old, $new );
});
```